# Eslint removing JSX component props indentation when rendering with ternary

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, react-props, indentation

I want indentation of component props when rendering with a ternary like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h2>
      blogs
    </h2>
    {user === null
      ? <LoginForm
          handleLogin={handleLogin}
          username={username}
          setUsername={setUsername}
          password={password}
          setPassword={setPassword} />
      : <BlogForm />
    }
  </div>
);
```

I cannot figure out what setting is causing my auto-format on save to remove the props indentation from `<LoginForm />` in this instance. The indented props are even in a lint error state when un-indented, but if I manually indent them and save the file, they are forced into the un-indented state. Seems like something is conflicting somewhere, but I cannot identify where.

Here is my `.eslintrc.cjs` file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'airbnb-base'
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs', 'vite.config.js'],
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 'latest', sourceType: 'module' },
  settings: { react: { version: '18.2' } },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    eqeqeq: 'error',
    'no-trailing-spaces': 'error',
    'object-curly-spacing': [
      'error', 'always',
    ],
    'arrow-spacing': [
      'error', { before: true, after: true },
    ],
    'no-console': 0,
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': [2, { maximum: 1 }],
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': [2, 'multiline'],
    'react/jsx-indent-props': [2, { indentMode: 2, ignoreTernaryOperator: false }],
  },
};
```

I admit I am not the greatest with setting up eslint properly so if you see any other glaring issues feel free to let me know. Thanks for your help!